# What kind of machine learning algorithm can I use?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a data set of tweets regarding vaccines.  They have been collected from an API because they have keywords like "flu, measles, MMR, vaccine" etc.

I need to find tweets specifically about measles and the outbreak that occurred in California this past February.  It isn't enough to search the data set for words like "California" and "Measles" because tweets like "MMR vaccination rates in Palo Alto on the rise" are about measles and California, but wont be captured by a naive search.

Are there any unsupervised algorithms that could help me out?

Comment: You could use a simple binary classifier.

Answer (score 2):

A couple ideas:

1. If you have a large data set of tweets, you could try using [latent semantic indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) to find out which terms are semantically related based on their usage and co-occurrence. Then after transformation, you can apply some document similarity metric, e.g. cosine similarity, to find tweets most relevant to your queries, e.g. "California measles".
2. Use knowledge or lexical databases like [DBPedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/) and [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to calculate semantic relatedness between your query and the text of your tweets, or to identify tweets with related concepts.